# Slim3 error. Can't find class

Tags: php, ubuntu, slim-3

I'm trying to make my slim3 application work on my VPS, but so far, I've had no luck.
It works 100% on my windows machine, but when I move it to my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS, it is not working. I get this message `"Message: Class 'app\views\auth\Auth' not found"`. The problem is, that I have no clue what is wrong. The class name is correct, and namespaces etc. are also correct.
Feel free to ask me any questions you might have, in order to help me.

My container looks like this:

```
$container['auth'] = function($container) {
    return new \App\views\Auth\Auth;
  };
```

My composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^2.2",
        "illuminate/database": "^5.4",
        "Respect/Validation": "^1.1",
        "slim/csrf": "^0.8.1",
        "slim/flash": "^0.2.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your ```composer.json``` file?
Also, did you run ```composer install``` on the server?

Comment: Yes I did. Updating thread with composer.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but perhaps the problem is with the case. ```app``` and ```App``` will be treated the same way on Windows machines. But on Unix systems case does matter, so ```app``` and ```App``` are different  things on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yea. I read that somewhere. We changed it, but it still isn't working :/

Comment: Here is an image: http://prntscr.com/ewh8sj

Comment: It's likey that @Rooxie is right, check namespace case.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to install composer locally in the project directory.That would help you.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment. Please add more text to your answer in order to help the OP get his question answered. At it's current state this is less helpful than most comments here.